# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Nginx reverse proxy for Node.js App after I installed SSL Certificates

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl

After I installed SSL Certificates from Letsencrypt Certbot, I can no longer access my site. Before I installed the SSL Certificates everything was acting as normal, but now I'm getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from chrome. I also attached a photo of a link tracer site that just shows it redirecting to the same link over and over.[image]

Nginx default file

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ppealliance.com www.ppealliance.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; #whatever port your app runs on
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ppealliance.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ppealliance.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = www.ppealliance.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = ppealliance.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name ppealliance.com www.ppealliance.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: **YOUR DOMAIN IS USING CLOUDFLARE.** You probably didn't set 'Full' SSL in CloudFlare so it is _receiving_ HTTPS from the browser or client but forwarding HTTP to your server, causing your server to return a redirect telling the client to use HTTPS -- which it already did -- and this cycle repeats until the client gives up.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 sure but, when I do set cloudflare to full nothing changes. Now what happens is it returns an error 500 and Nginx saids 

[error] 1124640#1124640: *2204 upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream, client: IP Go Here, server: ppealliance.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "www.ppealliance.com"

Comment: now the Url tracer I was using was able to access my site with a code of 200, but I still can't

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for your help I got it working, what ended up happening in the end is my code checked if the user had a cookie, if they had that cookie they would be sent home, but when you got to home, home would check if you have the same cookie, if they do they would be sent to home, then home would check if they have the same cookie, if they do they would be sent to home.. you see the point.